# Set jQuery function to a context of "this" - knobknob.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [knobknob.js](https://github.com/martinaglv/KnobKnob), which is really great. The only downside is that if I call the plugin on multiple objects, then it tries to do its work on all of them. How do I change my code to work on just "this" $('.control') instead of "all" $('.control') objects?

```
$('.control').knobKnob({
    snap : 1,
    value: 30,
    turn : function(ratio){
        numBars = Math.round(colorBars.length*ratio);

        // Update the dom only when the number of active bars
        // changes, instead of on every move

        var perc = Math.ceil(ratio * 100);
        $(".dimper").text(perc);


        if(numBars === lastNum){
            return false;
        }
        lastNum = numBars;

        colorBars.removeClass('active').addClass('gray').slice(0, numBars).addClass('activer').removeClass('gray');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know knobknob, but looping before using `.konbKnob()` wouldn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by looping?

Comment: Using `.each` like strah's answer!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you and @Karl-AndréGagnon so much! I got everything to work and using .each(function(i, el) on a parent function was the way I did it. I wouldn't have come to that solution without your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) Now up vote and accept strah's answer so the world can see that it work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest fix (without changing too much) would be this:

```
$('.control').each(function(i, el){
    $(el).knobKnob({
        snap : 1,
        value: 30,
        turn : function(ratio){
            numBars = Math.round(colorBars.length*ratio);

            // Update the dom only when the number of active bars
            // changes, instead of on every move

            var perc = Math.ceil(ratio * 100);
            $(".dimper").text(perc);


            if(numBars === lastNum){
                return false;
            }
            lastNum = numBars;

            colorBars.removeClass('active').addClass('gray').slice(0, numBars).addClass('activer').removeClass('gray');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: It will throw an error : `knobKnob is undefined (or is not a function)`. I'll let you figure out why :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Jquery selector to reference certain ids of elements on your page:

```
<div id="control1"></div>



$('#control1').knobKnob({
  yada yada
});
```